# Creating A Barplot with the Middle Removed with ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2, bar-chart, visualization

I was wondering if anyone knows how to create the sort of plot shown in figure H at this link: https://www.nature.com/articles/s41586-023-05896-x/figures/1

By removing the middle, one can focus at the ends, where most of the important information is. I was hoping that a package or vignette exists that explains how to do this w/ggplot, or if only a more manual solution is possible.

Also, I would be curious to learn the proper name for this sort of chart, if one exists.

[image]

Comment: look at `ggbreak` - vignette here: https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/ggbreak/vignettes/ggbreak.html  They call this a 'Gap plot' but I don't know if that's a generally used term.

Comment: Or consider log transformation for instance instead

Comment: searching on google for gap plot or gapped axis plot appears to be returning results similar to what I want, which makes me optimistic that it may be a somewhat common name

Comment: I am hoping to be able to display the variation in its natural units, which rules out a log transformation